# Lumen 7.0 version "Call to a member function hash_password() on null"

Tags: laravel, api, class, lumen

hash_password function not call (any other functions inside UService class)

this "UService.php" file include App\Http\Services\UService.php

[image]

this is the controller i called this "hash_password function" and error generating line is underlined

[image]

3rd image showing error is coming. I'm new to lumen framework.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try calling `dd($this->uService);` at the top of the `register` method.

Comment: it passing Null value

Comment: i added folder path above. its having inside Http folder

Comment: Try another `dd($this->uService);` under `$this->uService = new UService'; in the `__constructor` method.

Comment: same issue coming above image one. not printing inside constructor

Comment: Let me help you on face-to-face mode. It seems like needing runtime debugging.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222911/discussion-between-uda123-and-elektakode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `register` method as follows;

```
public function register(UserRegisterRequest $request, UService $uService, User $user) {
    $password_hash = $uService->hash_password($request->password);
    $user->createUser($request, $password_hash);
    $success_message = "registration completed success";
    return $uService->is200Response($success_message);
}
```